# Image not rendering as pdf in visualforce page when adding data:image/jpeg;base64 as an image property

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, jquery, pdf, images

I need to render an image in Visualforce as pdf.
When I load the page without the renderAs="pdf" the image loads

But the same image doesn't render in pdf except for a small box.

**Visualforce page to render the image:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="CasePDFContentGenerator" standardStylesheets="false" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" applyBodyTag="false" action="{!updatePrintFlag}" renderAs="pdf">

<body>
    <c:PDFContentGenerator conObj="{!printInstance}"></c:PDFContentGenerator>
</body>
```

**VF component**

```
<apex:component>
<apex:attribute type="CasePDFContentGenerator" name="conObj" description="con object instance"/>
<apex:repeat id="caseDetails" value="{!conObj.caseList}" var="case">
    <div style="page-break-after: always;" id="map">
        <!--THIS IS WHERE I PASS THE ID to the component safedropimagecomponent-->
   <c:imagecomponent dropid="6cb39aba-65d1-4aad-817d-b51c2118e6b4"></c:imagecomponent>
    </div>
</apex:repeat>
```

Please find my **jquery script** in the imagecomponent , which I am using to handle the id passed from VF component.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        var dropId = '574cae51-184b-4257-af2b-7cd6a55fc7e4';//Hard-coded for testing purpose
            var text = "";

            if(dropId != '') {

                ImageComponentController.getArticleImage(
                    dropId,
                    function(result, event) {
                        if(event.type === 'exception') {
                            setSafeDropResponse('ERROR: ' + event.statusCode + ': ' + JSON.stringify(event));

                        } else if (event.status) {
                            if(result.isError == true) {
                                setSafeDropResponse(result.errorMessage);

                            } else {
                                setSafeDropResponse($('<img/>').prop('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + result.imageBody));

                            }
                        } else {
                            console.log('ERROR:', event);
                        }

                    }
                );
            } else {
                setSafeDropResponse('No guidId Set');
            }
        //});
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setSafeDropResponse($response) {
        var $wrapper;
        if(typeof $response === 'string') {
            $wrapper = jQuery('<div />').text($response);
        } else {
            $wrapper = $response;
        }
        console.log('test' + JSON.stringify($wrapper));
        jQuery('#wrapper-image').empty().append($wrapper);
    }
</script>
```

I am assuming, I need to handle this portion differently, but cannot think of what?
Please advise.

```
else {setSafeDropResponse($('<img/>').**prop('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + result.imageBody));**}
```

Comment: JS does not work in renderAs="pdf"

Comment: Seems like I will need to look for alternate solution as pdf rendering doesnt support it.Thanks all.